# Fragment not associated with a fragment manager after screen rotation in Android

Tags: android, closures, fragment, fragmentmanager, screen-rotation

I have a problem I can't solve. I have two fragments, one called "NotificationListFragment" that can navigate to a second fragment called "InfoNotificationFragment". Before calling the second fragment, I pass two parameters through the Bundle object:

- A closure of type "() -> Unit" that needs to be executed when the second fragment is closed;
- An object of type "MessageNotificationCompatible".
  Both are passed as Parcelable objects. The closure is set inside a class called "TrackedReference", which contains a map of objects of type "WeakReference", in order to avoid implementing marshalling.

Let me show you how this is done in the "NotificationListFragment" class:

```
adapter.action.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { action ->
            when(action) {
                is NotificationAction.SelectionAction -> {
                    val message = action.infoNotification.toNotificationMessage()

                    val handler: () -> Unit = {
                        markInfoNotificationAsReadInRV(message.data.getID())
                        findNavController().navigateUp()
                    }

                    val closeHandler : CloseHandlerCompatible = CloseHandler(handler)

                    val b = Bundle()
                    b.putParcelable(InfoNotificationFragment.MESSAGE_KEY, message)
                    b.putParcelable(InfoNotificationFragment.CLOSURE_KEY, TrackedReference(closeHandler))

                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notificationListFragment_to_infoNotificationFragment, b)
                }
            }
        }
```

Inside the "InfoNotificationFragment" class, within the "onCreate()" method, the parameters passed through the Bundle are retrieved:

```
arguments?.let { bundle->
            val closure : TrackedReference<*>

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                message = bundle.getParcelable(MESSAGE_KEY, NotificationMessageCompatible::class.java)
                closure = bundle.getParcelable(CLOSURE_KEY, TrackedReference::class.java) as TrackedReference<*>
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                message = bundle.getParcelable(MESSAGE_KEY)
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                closure = (bundle.getParcelable(CLOSURE_KEY) as? TrackedReference<*>)!!
            }

            closeHandler = (closure.get as CloseHandlerCompatible).closeHandler
            closure.removeStrongReference()
        }
```

This second fragment has a button that, when clicked, calls the closure that was passed to it as a parameter:

```
binding.closeButton.setOnClickListener {

            // Need for smart cast
            val message = message ?: return@setOnClickListener

            // I mark the notification it as read in memory
            viewModel.markInfoNotificationAsRead(message.data.getID())

            // I call the closeHandler method
            this.closeHandler()
        }
```

The problem I'm encountering is the following: everything works correctly following the standard flow. However, when the app remains in the background for a long time, and the activity and fragment view are recreated, I can no longer call the "findNavController().navigateUp()" method inside the closure.

Since the problem occurs at an unspecified time, I tried to simulate the same situation by attempting to activate the screen orientation (which is disabled by default for this activity).

Actually, by rotating the screen, I find myself in the same situation as when the app is in the background, so I can simulate this problem. In any case, the exception that I get when I try to call the "findNavController().navigateUp()" method after rotating the screen is the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.zucchetti.fq.qid, PID: 29563
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NotificationListFragment{846f563} (fc633911-2609-4220-8236-acfda3b0a01b) not associated with a fragment manager.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager(Fragment.java:1107)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment$Companion.findNavController(NavHostFragment.kt:375)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
        at it.zucchetti.qauthenticator.ui.notificationlist.NotificationListFragment$onSuccess$1$handler$1.invoke(NotificationListFragment.kt:158)
        at it.zucchetti.qauthenticator.ui.notificationlist.NotificationListFragment$onSuccess$1$handler$1.invoke(NotificationListFragment.kt:155)
        at it.zucchetti.qauthenticator.ui.notification.info.InfoNotificationFragment.bindData$lambda$1(InfoNotificationFragment.kt:110)
        at it.zucchetti.qauthenticator.ui.notification.info.InfoNotificationFragment.$r8$lambda$Trhe-1LjjI1Cfn283v0VQLwE1u0(Unknown Source:0)
        at it.zucchetti.qauthenticator.ui.notification.info.InfoNotificationFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

I tried to change the way to go back to the previous fragment, to save the fragment's state, to save the NavHostFragment's state, but I still haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to "manually" navigate up without using the findNotificationListFragment reference to the findNavController?! As the fragments were recreated that instance is lost (what is look like). 
Also, isntead of passing bundles like this, why dont you use a shared view model to handle data between fragments?

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos Do you mean using a transaction by manual navigation? Because I've tried a bit of everything but nothing has worked. Also, is it true that I could make a shared view model, but for the purpose of the problem, what would change if the reference to the old fragment is still lost? What solution would you adopt?

Comment: by manually I mean using the findNavController().navigateUp() but from the infoNotificationFragment perspective without passing the reference from the first one; or you could try to get the activity reference like "requireActivity().navigateup (it has been a while that I use the navigation library) or trying to get the fragment manager from there (the activity).